# mod_evasive with Apache/2.2.16 dosn't work when I use curl

Tags: apache-2.2

I have apache server:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)    
Architecture:   64-bit   
threaded:     no    
forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/experimental/itk"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

I have installed module mod_evasive with test configuration:

```
DOSPageCount 2
DOSPageInterval 1
DOSSiteCount 50
DOSSiteInterval 1
DOSBlockingPeriod 10
```

When i press F5 several times it works fine and i can see 403. But when i use curl or wget:

```
while true; do curl -i -A "Mozilla/5.0" http://url; done
while true ; do { wget --output-document=x.txt --no-proxy http://url ; } ; done
```

it does not work at all.

Do you have any ideas?
Where to find the cause?

Answer (score -1):

Increase the `DOSPageInterval` and/or the `DOSSiteInterval` to, for example, 10.  That will give you a longer window in which to trigger mod_evasive.